# Swift UI facetime link fail with (OSStatus error -10814.)

Tags: swift, swiftui, facetime, lsapplicationqueriesschemes

Trying to connect to face time from my aplication,
with the user input email id or phone number
but getting **OSStatus error -10814**

Code to connect to face time :

```
                  if let url = URL(string: "facetime://18883223846" ) {
                     if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
                        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:],completionHandler:nil)
                     }
                  }
```

NOTE :
*number given here is sample (how to test face time even if friend less number)
even if correct number is given getting same error*

Error:

```
     -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "facetime://18883223846" - error: "The operation couldn’t be 
       completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)
```

Error got on execution of  `UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:],completionHandler:nil)` alone

```
       Failed to open URL facetime://18883223846: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10814 " 
         (null)" UserInfo={_LSLine=247, _LSFunction=-[_LSDOpenClient 
           openURL:options:completionHandler:]}
```

Info Plist:

```
      <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
          <array>
            <string>facetime</string>
          </array>
```

Comment: Are you testing this on a physical device? What device if so? Works on Xcode 11.4.1, iOS 13.4, iPhone X

Comment: Testing on simulator
 xcode version 11.3.1

Comment: The simulator doesn't support FaceTime. you are going to have to use a physical device.